# How can I zoom in on a div element on scroll using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I'm trying to achieve here is that when I scroll on a particular div here `.ball`, it should scale up to 1.5.
but when I'm not scrolling on that ball div it should shrink down to it's original height and width. 
Here I'm using `window` method to do this trick and as soon as I scroll ball scale up which isn't what I'm trying to do. What can I use instead of window method and is there any other approach to do achieve this?

```js
const ball = document.querySelector('.ball');

window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=> {
    if (scroll) {
        ball.classList.add('active');
    } else {
        ball.classList.remove('active');
    }
});
```

```css
      .ball {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        background-color: orange;
      }

      .ball.active {
          transform: scale(1.5);
          position: fixed;
      }
      body {
        height: 150vh;
      }
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Comment: Do you mean when you stop scrolling the class should be removed?

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Yes, stop scrolling on that div.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a setTimeout function to remove the class after a short period after the scroll. Do not forget to clear the timeout otherwise it will lead to weird behaviour. (as suggested by Lakshya when I was answering to the question).

To make the ball smoothly transition, I would add a css transition as shown bellow.

```js
const ball = document.querySelector('.ball');
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
let scrollTimeout;
    
container.addEventListener('scroll', ()=> {
    ball.classList.add('active');
    clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(()=> ball.classList.remove('active'), 100);
});
```

```css
 .ball {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        background-color: orange;
        transition: transform 0.3s ease;
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
        left: 50px;
      }

      .ball.active {
          transform: scale(1.5);
      }
      
      
      .container{
        width: 100%;
        background: red;
        overflow: scroll;
        height: 500px;
      }
      
      .inside_container{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 2000px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inside_container">
        <div class="ball"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. Sorry but I want to zoom in the ball when only I scroll on div. Now if I scroll anywhere on the page, ball will scale up to 1.5. It's because of that you and me both are window method for listening the scroll event.

Comment: Let me edit it to be linked to a div :) you can use onscroll on a div to bind a function to a div (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp) I'll update the code

Comment: Yes, please and yes I've seen this code on w3schools but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: I used another trick to make it work. Let me know if that looks as you wanted it to. I created two more divs: One that serves as a container you can scroll in and another one inside to set the height to be higher so you have room to scroll in. Something to note is that to make effect like this one smoother & easier, you can check GSAP ScrollTrigger js plugin. It will help you a lot achieving such effects

Comment: Hi thanks for the tip but I don't think I should be using setTimeout cause like every 100ms or every 1s it'll shrink back to it's original form. Think of it is as user is looking at some table and it consist some data. He/she scrolls to zoom in but in 1 or 2 seconds it'll be zoom out again. so that's the problem, and also use position sticky and set it to top: 0, that way it won't be always on the top of the page, only on .container parent. Try to solve this zoom in-out problem, and thanks very much. +1.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches could be delaying the removal of `.active` class on `ball` by `200`ms such that each time you try to scroll again, the timer is cleared and a new one starts to do the same. A debounce approach in a nutshell.

```js
const ball = document.querySelector('.ball');
let scrollTimeout;

window.addEventListener('scroll', ()=> {
    ball.classList.add('active');
    clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(()=> ball.classList.remove('active'),200);
});
```

```css
.ball {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        background-color: orange;
      }

      .ball.active {
          transform: scale(1.5);
          position: fixed;
      }
      body {
        height: 150vh;
      }
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

Comment: Not working properly. Window method won't work for this because I want to scroll on that particular div. Now if I scroll anywhere on the page ball will scale up.